# How to put all elements' content in array using jQuery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, element

```
<div id="main">
<p>Text1</p>
<p>Text2</p>
<p>Text3</p>
</di>
```

Result should be :

```
["text1","text2","text3"]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jQuery provides [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) for this:

```
var items = $('#main p').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

`.map()` iterates over its elements, invoking a function on each of them and recording the return value of the function in a new array, which it returns.

You could also have solved this with a simple `.each()`:

```
var items = [];

$('#main p').each(function (i, e) {
  items.push($(e).text());
});
```

Comment: Is not there a more concise way

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var p = $('#main p').map(function () {
        return '"' + $(this).text() + '"';
    }).get().join(',');
    p = "[" + p + "]";
```

map() lets you iterate over each match and get a value from it, which is inserted into an array-like object. get() then returns it as a Javascript array, and .join makes the array into a string.