# put content of all elements of class into array..why do i get these error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load text of all divs that have a particular class into an array, but this

```
var temp = $('.theClass').text();
    temp = temp.toArray();
    console.log(temp);
```

keeps giving me the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'toArray'`

And

```
var tempArr = [];
var temp = $('.theClass').text();

for (var t in temp){

    tempArr.push(t);
}
console.log(tempArr);
```

results in an array filled with many, many objects within objects just filled with integers.
[image: screenshot of chrome console]

An explanation of how to do this properly can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948779/1252748), but I wonder if someone could provide me with an explanation for why I get these errors. Thanks!

Comment: `.text()` returns  a string....Why didn't you just use the code in the answer you linked?

Comment: @Esailija i'm not trying to figure out how to do it, i'm trying to understand why these methods don't work. maybe understand a little more about how  jquery and javascript work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to iterate over each element of the matched set and return some data (in this case, the text). You can then use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to convert the resulting jQuery object into an actual array:

```
var arr = $('.theClass').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Your first attempt fails because the `text` method returns a string, and strings don't have a `toArray` method (hence your "Object has no method" error).

Your second attempt fails because you're iterating over the string with the `for...in` loop. This loop iterates over the characters of the string. Each iteration `t` is assigned the index of the character, so you end up with an array, with one element for each character in the string. You should never really be using a `for...in` loop for iterating over anything other than object properties, and even then, you should always include a `hasOwnProperty` check.