# Iterate over and traverse DOM tree

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iteration, tree-traversal

#### Problem

I have a monthly subscription based *WordPress* website, which gives users monthly content and automatically moves them to the next subscription at the end of each month (but requires payment to proceed). Users have a page which lists all the subscription levels (and which ones they've purchased) on the website. I am using a plugin called *Ultimate Membership Pro* to accomplish this.

The problem comes in when we have had to integrate it with *WooCommerce* (for good reason). Because of this, when a user has purchased a subscription level it still gives the option to purchase it again on the subscription levels page.

I disabled the repeat purchase functionality with php, but I need to the purchase button to be disabled dynamically on the subscription list page (an example of which is listed in the fiddles below).

#### Attempted Solution

Using a `foreach` loop and some *DOM tree traversing*, jQuery finds the name of the level where it is listed at the top and disables its button on the page. This works just fine.

The problem is that it doesn't work when there is more than one level listed.

I have two fiddles which demonstrate the issue.

*PS because I am working in Wordpress my jQuery is written in no-conflict mode.*

#### Examples & Code

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.ihc-level-item .ihc-level-item-title').each(function() {
    // Get the level name
    var lvlName = $('.ihc-account-subscr-list .ihc-level-name').text();
    // Find that level on page
    if ($(this).html() == lvlName) {
      // Console log confirms its working
      console.log('Found level: ' + lvlName + ' on page.');
      $(this).closest('.ihc-level-item').children('.ihc-level-item-content').addClass('lvl-purchased');
    }
  });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ajikanfan/b5svgmuu/)
*Only one level listed*

[**Non working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ajikanfan/rf24hh5f/)
*Two levels listed*

Comment: `$('.ihc-account-subscr-list .ihc-level-name')` returns more than one element, hence `.text()` would contain the textual contents of all of them

Comment: Perhaps you meant `var lvlName = $(this).parent('.ihc-level-item').find('.ihc-account-subscr-list .ihc-level-name').text();`

Comment: @haim770 wow, that's interesting thank you ^^ you were right. I check and it stores all level names on page inside .ihc-level-name into one string. It would be nice if it could store it inside an array, but maybe I can extract the name somehow. The second suggestion returns an empty string, so I am not sure it would work :/

Comment: @haim770 `var lvlName = $('.ihc-account-subscr-list').find('.ihc-level-name').text();` this also works, but it also returns one concated string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using **meagar♦'s** answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948770/how-to-put-all-elements-content-in-array-using-jquery)

I just needed to store the level names in an array and access it and such then presto!

```
$('.ihc-level-item .ihc-level-item-title').each(function() {
  // Get the level names and store inside array
  var array = [];
  var lvlName = $('.ihc-account-subscr-list .ihc-level-name').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get();
  console.log(lvlName);
  for (var i=0; i<lvlName.length; i++) {
    // Find that level on page
    if ($(this).html() == lvlName[i]) {
      $(this).closest('.ihc-level-item').children('.ihc-level-item-content').addClass('lvl-purchased');
    } else {
      console.log('Couldn\'t find level on page.');
    }
  }
});
```